# Is there a away to merge a QGridLayout of a child widget in the QGridLayout of the parent dialog?

Tags: c++, qt, qt-designer, qtwidgets

When writing grid-like dialogs I often happen to need multiple columns having the same structure, with the number of columns known only at runtime (think configuration parameters for multiple instances of the same kind of object).

[image: desired result]

In this situation, the regular Qt widgets designer falls short, because, although I can comfortably design the various headers and a "prototype column", there is no easy way to replicate the creation of such column at runtime (all the widgets are created together in `setupUi`, and there's no easy way to clone `QWidget`s).

An alternative may be to split up the "prototype column" in a separate custom widget (that aligns the child widgets using a `QVBoxLayout`) and instantiate such custom widget at runtime in the parent dialog, putting those instances in a `QHBoxLayout`.

The problem with this approach is that the widgets of different columns may end up horizontally unaligned, as each `QVBoxLayout` performs its calculations on its own without considering the other columns, so the desired grid layout is easily messed up.

[image]

The only other possibility that comes to mind would be to split up the prototype column in a separate widget as described but, instead of putting the custom widget in a `QHBoxLayout`, "stealing" its children and putting them correctly aligned in the parent `QGridLayout`. This results in the desired graphical effect, but reparenting the children and hiding the custom widget feels a bit like a hack.

Now, my question is twofold:

- are there potential issues I may be unaware of in happily reparenting such children widgets, given that their "fake" container isn't going to do anything particular with them?
- are there better approaches to this issue? Ideally I would think about some method to merge `QGridLayout` of children widgets with a "main" grid, but there seems not to be such a thing.

Comment: Sounds like a tableview with custom item delegates.

Comment: @ekhumoro: that would require to create the subwidgets via code, which is exactly what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: How about the prototype column approach, but you fix the height of the column elements in the designer? Either that or you have a method to apply the maximum height for each element to the heights of all the elements once `setupUI()` has run.

Comment: @MadPhysicist: that would kinda defeat the point of having layouts in first place...

Comment: You are actually trying to do a manual layout because you are not satisfied with how the layouts are communicating, so yes, it does defeat the purpose to some extent. Think of it as using the layouts to compute some maximum sizes for you automatically, then polling them and performing inter-layout communication manually.

Comment: Another possibility: create a widget subclass that maintains a map of all the components added to it. Each component's size is compared against a maximum stored in a static class-level map and either updated or used to update the global map, which pushes updates to all instances (somehow).